# Does saving pointer to array length update when length is updated?

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-contract

While using truffle to write tests I had something similar to the following in my contract and was getting an `invalid opcode` error.

```
var length = myList.length; // 2
delete myList[1];
myList.length = length - 1;
```

When I updated the code to the following it worked:

```
delete myList[1]
myList.length = myList.length - 1;
```

Why does the second code work, but the first throws `invalid opcode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those code snippets work fine, but your question and the first code snippet show an underlying confusion. In your first code snippet, `length` is not a "pointer." It's a new value that is assigned the value `2`, the current value of `myList.length`. No subsequent changes to `myList.length` will affect the value stored by `length`. There is no ongoing relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Both work for me. Make sure there are at least 2 elements in the array or look for the root cause in another place in your code.